# Install 'AR Foundation' along with 'ARKit XR Plugin' for iOS or 'ARCore XR Plugin' for Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, arcore

Currently, I have a Unity app using ARKit through AR Foundation (a library that supports both ARKit and ARCore). However, after installation and setup, when I select the "Horizontal" surface detection, the system still recognizes both horizontal and vertical surfaces.

How to only detect the horizontal surface?